# Unable to add x position to Pygame Sprite

Tags: python, pygame

**Problem**

My problem is that i'm trying to display 3 heart images on the screen, but when I wrote the code for it, it gives me an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 99, in <module>
    Game().new()
  File "main.py", line 38, in new
    Heart(self.allSprites, 10 * i + 5, self.health)
  File "classes\heart.py", line 5, in __init__
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, x, *args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.add(*groups)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

**What I want to happen**

I want their to be 3 heart images in a row on the top left.

Ex (rectangles represent heart images):

```
*****   *****  *****
*   *   *   *  *   *
*   *   *   *  *   *
*****   *****  *****
```

Each rectangle is `30px by 30px`, and is `15px` away from each other.

**Python Code**

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, *args):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, *args)

    self.image = 
    pygame.image.load("assets/img/vehicles/sports.png").convert_alpha()
    # self.image.fill(GREEN)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
    self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
    self.velX = 0
    self.displacement = 6
    self.lives = 3

class Heart(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, x, *args):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, *args)

    self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/img/heart.png").convert_alpha()
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (30, 30))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.top = 10

class Game(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
    self.running = True
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    self.allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.health = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.player = Player()

def new(self):
    # create a new game

    self.allSprites.add(self.player)

    # add obstacles to list
    for i in range(OBSTICLES_AMOUNT):
        Obstacle(self.allSprites, self.obstacles)

    # add hearts to list
    for i in range(self.player.lives):
        Heart(self.allSprites, 10 * i + 5, self.health)

    self.gameLoop()

def gameLoop(self):
    while self.running:
        self.allSprites.update()
        self.update()
        self.events()
        self.clock.tick(FPS)

def update(self):
    # updates game

    self.draw()
    self.collision()

    pygame.display.update()

def draw(self):
    # draws to screen

    self.screen.fill(BACKGROUND)

    self.allSprites.draw(self.screen)
    for sprites in self.obstacles:
        sprites.update()

    for sprites in self.health:
        sprites.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it turns out that I could not add another parameter with `*args`

ex: `def name(x, *args)`, so I changed the `x` pos when I added each heart image into the list.

**Code**

```
for i in range(self.player.lives):
        Heart(self.allSprites, self.health).rect.x = 30 * i
```

Answer (score 0):

Return to the `Sprite` class documentation and check the interface.  The second argument to `init` is the group(s) to which the sprite belongs.  You code sequence sends integers in that position:

In Game.new():

```
Heart(self.allSprites, 10 * i + 5, self.health)
```

In Heart.**init**():

```
def __init__(self, x, *args):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, *args)
```

Your `x` parameter is mapped to `allSprites`; *args contains only the pair of integers.